# Pointers in swift?

Tags: swift, pointers

I have following code. I want to create objects of questions which lead to some solution.

This is my Question object:

```
class Question {

    var question = String()
    var answers = [String]?()
    var prevQuestion:Question?
    var followingQuestions:[Question]?

    init (question: String, answers: [String]?) {
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
    }

}
```

And this is function that is supposed to make array of questions objects (objects with question without answer is answer):

```
func initializeObjects () {

    for i in 0...(questions.count - 1) {

        questionObjects.append(Question(question: questions[i], answers: answers[i]))

    }

    // Q1
    questionObjects[1 - 1].prevQuestion = nil
    questionObjects[1 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[2 - 1], questionObjects[3 - 1]]
    // Q2
    questionObjects[2 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[1 - 1]
    questionObjects[2 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[4 - 1], questionObjects[6 - 1]]
    // Q3
    questionObjects[3 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[1 - 1]
    questionObjects[3 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[5 - 1], questionObjects[8 - 1]]
    // Q4
    questionObjects[4 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[2 - 1]
    questionObjects[4 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[9 - 1]]
    // Q5
    questionObjects[5 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[3 - 1]
    questionObjects[5 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[8 - 1], questionObjects[11 - 1]]
    // Q6
    questionObjects[6 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[2 - 1]
    questionObjects[6 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[16 - 1], questionObjects[7 - 1]]
    // Q7
    questionObjects[7 - 1].prevQuestion = questionObjects[6 - 1]
    questionObjects[7 - 1].followingQuestions = [questionObjects[17 - 1], questionObjects[13 - 1]]

    // and so on ... 

} // end of initializeObjects()
```

But problem is, that for example in question #3 i want to put question #5 as one of following questions. But it's not yet fully configured. So I'd like to put address on this question to it, to have up do date data in it. Is possible to do it? Or there is another way? Thank you so much.

Comment: What actually went wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I feel stupid now. Probably nothing. I tested it in playground and it was giving me weird results and I couldn't figure out whats wrong but now it seems to be working correctly. So please sorry and thank you for your willingness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these two quotes from “The Swift Programming Language” iBook answers to your question. (Available for free @iBooks store)

> "If you have experience with C, C++, or Objective-C, you may know that these languages use pointers to refer to addresses in memory. A Swift constant or variable that refers to an instance of some reference type is similar to a pointer in C, but is not a direct pointer to an address in memory, and does not require you to write an asterisk (*) to indicate that you are creating a reference. Instead, these references are defined like any other constant or variable in Swift.”

---

> “Structure instances are always passed by value, and class instances are always passed by reference.”

---

So I think your code is ok, and you don't need to change your current solution.

Also, I suggest you to read "Assignment and Copy Behavior for Collection Types" topic from that book.